# How do you provision a VM programmatically with eg. React as frontend?

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine

I was wondering how cloud companies like GCP, Linode, AWS, Azure, ... communicate between the VM you deployed and the UI. How do they program that if you click a button, there will be a new VM created on their backend.

Basically how would i be able to make a clone of Linode or something with the option to manage VM's with a UI.

Can someone explain how to program this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/v1/userguide/install-linux.html, there's an awscli package. It's relatively trivial to wrap those commands behind a rest endpoint and allow a website to call those REST endpoints to spin up new services.

If you wanted to roll it yourself, again VMWare has server software that has APIs that will create new VMs for you